# Automigration annotation ERROR in Room with Java

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-room

inserting a new (BLOB) field, i modified schema of my room database in Android Studio.
After that i had to increment database version, too. I also added

```html
@Database(
   version = 2,
   entities = [
       Table1.class,
       Table2.class
   ],
   autoMigrations = [
       @AutoMigration (
           from = 1,
           to = 2
       ),
...
```

in the @Database annotation. Now i get the error "cannot resolve symbol @automigration" in the logcat and do not find a hint to solution.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

EDIT, full class:

```
@Database(entities = {Device.class, User.class, 
DeviceUserCrossRef.class},
    autoMigrations = {
            @AutoMigration (from = 1, to =2)
    }
    ,exportSchema = true,
    version = 2)
@TypeConverters({DateConverter.class, ImageConverter.class})
public abstract class DeviceDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

private static DeviceDatabase INSTANCE;

// Getter pro DAO
public abstract DeviceDao deviceDao();
public abstract UserDao userDao();
public abstract UserWithDevicesDao userWithDevicesDao();
public abstract DeviceWithUsersDao deviceWithUsersDao();

// Entwurfsmuster Singleton
// Nur eine Instanz der Klasse darf erstellt werden
public static DeviceDatabase getInstance(Context context) {

    // Haben wir schon eine Instanz erstellt
    if (INSTANCE == null) {

        // Sperre für andere Threads
        synchronized (DeviceDatabase.class) {

            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                // Nein, es gibt noch keine Instanz
                // -> eine neue Instanz erzeugen

                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.getApplicationContext(),
                        DeviceDatabase.class,
                        "database.sqlite"
                ).build();

            }
        }
    }

    return INSTANCE;
}


}
```

EDIT 2:
[image]

EDIT 3:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe that your issue is that you are **mixing Java and Kotlin code**.

In Kotlin a list of items can be specified within  square brackets **`[`** .... and **`]`** e.g. you have:-

```
entities = [Table1.class,Table2.class]
```

and

```
autoMigrations = [@AutoMigration (from = 1,to = 2)
```

i.e. lists according to **Kotlin**.

However `Table1.java`, `Tbale2.java` and  `@AutomMigration` are coded as **Java** items.

So you for **Kotlin** you should use:-

```
@Database(
    entities = [Table1::class,Table2::class],
    autoMigrations = [ AutoMigration(from = 1, to = 2)],
    exportSchema = true,
    version = 2
)
```

**or for Java** you should use :-

```
@Database(
        entities = {Table1.class,Table2.class},
        autoMigrations = {
                @AutoMigration(from = 1, to =2)
        }
        ,exportSchema = true,
        version = 2
)
```

**Example/Demo**

The following demonstrates **using Kotlin**:-

```
@Entity
data class Table1(
    @PrimaryKey
    val table1Id: Long?=null,
    val table1Name: String
    ,@ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "FFX")    val table1Blob: ByteArray /*<<<<<<<<<< ADDED for V2 */
)
@Entity class Table2(
    @PrimaryKey
    val table2Id: Long?=null,
    val table2Name: String
)
@Dao
interface TheDaoInterface {
    @Insert
    fun insert(table1: Table1): Long
    @Insert
    fun insert(table2: Table2): Long
}
@Database(
    entities = [Table1::class,Table2::class],
    autoMigrations = [ AutoMigration(from = 1, to = 2)/*<<<<<<<<<< ADDED FOR V2 */],
    exportSchema = true,
    version = /*1*/ 2 /*<<<<<<<<<< CHANGED FOR V2 */
)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getTheDaoInterface(): TheDaoInterface

    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase?=null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance==null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

With the resultant database being:-

[image: ![enter image description here]

and **using Java**

```
@Entity
class Table1 {
    @PrimaryKey
    Long table1Id=null;
    String table2Name;
    byte[] table1Blob; /*<<<<<<<<<< ADDED FOR V2 */
}
@Entity
class Table2 {
    @PrimaryKey
    Long table2Id=null;
    String table2Name;
}

@Database(
        entities = {Table1.class,Table2.class},
        autoMigrations = {
                @AutoMigration(from = 1, to =2)
        }
        ,exportSchema = true,
        version = 2
)
abstract class TheDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    abstract TheDao getTheDao();

    private static volatile TheDatabase instance;
    static TheDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance==null) {
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase.class,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

[image]

- The identity hashes (hash based upon the schema) clearly showing two different database (i.e. Kotlin V Java)

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you very much for your answer, but the mixture of Java/Kotlin is not the problem, see picture above, but it still cannot resolve...

Comment: @luckymanStefan I suspect that your dependencies are incorrect. For java you only need the runtime (implementation) and room-compiler(annotationProcessor) dependencies in the build.gradle(Module) e.g. `implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.0-beta01'` and `annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.0-beta01'`

Comment: Sorry Mike, updating dependencies also does not help... See image in original post...

Comment: I would suggest trying a new project, as you can see, the demos above work. You may want to try a clean project and a rebuild project first (in the Build menu).

Comment: After triggering a "project sync" the AutoMigration symbol was finally accepted. But how can i trigger this, because in my case i just clocked ok on a message box with this sync option!?

Comment: @luckymanStefan if you make changes to the build gradle then the sync option appears, you should always sync after making changes.

Comment: Although i have added an automigration from 2 to 3, there is still a problem with the new field "description"...